# PhpStorm AutoFormat: Align Multiline String Concatenation

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpstorm, autoformatting

The Zend format rule states that multiline string concatenation should be aligned under the "=" sign:

```
string $foo = "Lorem "
            . "ipsum";
```

PhpStorm does not seem to support this - it either aligns x spaces indented or it aligns the dot with the opening brace:

```
string $foo = "Lorem "
              . "ipsum";
```

Tested in V2017.1.2.

Anyone who managed to configure PS to comply to Zend format rules?

Comment: have you set the `Code Style` for `PHP` from Zend format?

Comment: The code style is created based on the Zend code style.

Answer (score 2):

They're aligned, if you reformat the whole file, e.g.:

```
function test(
    string $foo
    = "Lorem "
    . "ipsum"
) {
}
```

Do you have a full code sample?

Comment: I always reformat whole file, and it did not work for me. The difference is: I do not have a line break before the equals sign.

Comment: Well, Zend code style inserts a line break there. You can submit a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes to make possible implementing your code style